# How to count necklaces with this additional requirement?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, totient-function, necklace-and-bracelets

I've recently dug into the idea of [necklaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29) for a project I'm working on, and it's *almost* exactly what I'm looking for. The way I understand it, the general necklace-counting function is essentially cyclic permutations with repetition. However, for the particular situation I am trying to evaluate, there is one additional requirement.

So for this necklace-counting function, there are $n$ beads and $3$ colors. However, for each counted necklace, it must also be the case that the (absolute) difference between the number of beads of the $2^{nd}$ color and the number of beads of the $3^{rd}$ color, is divisible by $3$. There can be any number of beads of the $1^{st}$ color. I haven't the slightest idea how to subtract cases that fail this test from the original general necklace-counting function. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you considered counting necklaces $(a,b,c)$ and then summing?

Comment: Math mode isn't intended for italicizing text; it yields the wrong spacing for that. Usually text is italicized by enclosing it in asterisks. In the present case, where you want the italicized text as a superscript, you can use e.g. `3^{\mathit{rd}}` for $3^{\mathit{rd}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a divisor $d\mid n$, there are $\phi(d)$ elements of $C_n$ of order $d$ that have $\frac nd$ orbits. In the usual count without your constraint, they leave $3^\frac nd$ necklaces invariant, since you can independently choose one of $3$ colours for each orbit.

If $3\mid d$, then all colour counts are divisible by $3$ so the constraint has no effect.

If $3\not\mid d$, consider the three necklaces you get if you pick one orbit and colour it in each of the three colours, with the same arbitrary colours in each case for the remaining orbits. The constraint is fulfilled in exactly one of these $3$ cases. Thus the number of admissible invariant necklaces is $3^{\frac nd-1}$.

Then by Burnside’s lemma the total count of admissible necklaces is

$$
\frac1n\left(\sum_{3\mid d\mid n}\phi(d)3^\frac nd+\frac13\sum_{3\not\mid d\mid n}\phi(d)3^\frac nd\right)\;.
$$

For $3\not\mid n$, this is just one third of the usual necklace count. For $3\mid n$, if you write $n=3^rs$ with $3\not\mid s$, this is

$$
\frac1n\left(\sum_{d\mid\frac n3}\phi(3d)3^\frac n{3d}+\frac13\sum_{d\mid s}\phi(d)3^\frac nd\right)\;.
$$

Comment: This is honestly so far beyond me that I can't even say for sure if it's right. But it certainly sounds right. Thank you!

Comment: @QuaternionsRock: I'm sorry, I had assumed since you linked to the Wikipedia article on necklaces without any comment that you understood how the count for unconstrained necklaces there is obtained. Let me know if you'd like an explanation for any particular aspect of this.

Comment: Actually, I do have one quick question. With the general necklace counting function, $\phi(d)\alpha^{\frac n d)}$ is interchangeable with $\phi(\frac n d) \alpha^d$ which is far more computationally efficient (due to the iterative nature of the $\phi$ function. Is this also true for your solution?

Comment: And as a response to your comment, as much as I appreciate it, I'm just a freshman in college at the moment. I understand how to implement the polynomial with my coding project, but I haven't even begun to understand how the polynomial is obtained. I'm not even sure what an orbit is. I also just learned what the $\sum_{a \mid b}$ notation actually means yesterday. So I'll get back to you in a few years once I've taken some more math courses hahaha

Comment: @QuaternionsRock: I'm not sure what you mean by "the iterative nature of the $\phi$ function". The form I gave in the last line of the answer was more geared toward succinctness (getting rid of the divisibility conditions on the summation index) than toward computational efficiency. If you want to actually evaluate the sum, the most straightforward way, and possibly also the computationally most efficient, would be to use the first form, where you have the same summation as in the standard count except you need to check whether $3\mid d$ and if not divide the contribution by $3$.

Comment: @QuaternionsRock: To answer your concrete question: In the first form, $d$ and $\frac nd$ are not interchangeable, since $3\mid\frac nd$ is a different condition than $3\mid d$. In the second form, in the first sum $d$ and $\frac n{3d}$ are interchangeable, but I don't know whether that helps, since neither of them is the argument of $\phi$. In the second sum, you can write the summand as

$$
\phi(d)\left(3^{3^r}\right)^\frac sd\;,
$$

as if you're counting necklaces with $3^{3^r}$ colours and $s$ beads, so in that case $d$ and $\frac sd$ are interchangeable.

Comment: Just realized how stupid my question was and deleted it. Nevermind. Thanks for the help!